How to automate file upload in chrome using chrome extension script?
Basically, this is my problem. I want to automate file upload onto the windows file upload GUI through code, but I don't know how to do so. I can't use Selenium because Selenium opens up a new browser and I don't want that. I'll likely be using a chrome extension to do this. Can someone help?
